# Electron and sequelize error: the dialect sqlite is not supported

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, electron

I'm trying to use [sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) and sqlite with [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) in a desktop application but get the following error when running the app via `npm start` (which runs `node_modules/.bin/electron .`):

> Uncaught Error: The dialect sqlite is not supported. (Error: Please install sqlite3 package manually)

I've installed sequelize and sqlite with `npm install --save sequelize sqlite`. When I run the models file directly via `node models.js`, everything works fine:

```
$ node models.js
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Users` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `username` VARCHAR(255), `birthday` DATETIME, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`Users`)
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`username`,`birthday`,`updatedAt`,`createdAt`) VALUES (NULL,'janedoe','1980-07-19 22:00:00.000 +00:00','2015-09-06 11:18:52.412 +00:00','2015-09-06 11:18:52.412 +00:00');
{ id: 1,
  username: 'janedoe',
  birthday: Sun Jul 20 1980 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST),
  updatedAt: Sun Sep 06 2015 13:18:52 GMT+0200 (CEST),
  createdAt: Sun Sep 06 2015 13:18:52 GMT+0200 (CEST) }
```

So the problem is specific to using sequelize with electron. All files are shown below.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node_modules/.bin/electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.31.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "sequelize": "^3.7.1",
    "sqlite3": "^3.0.10"
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
var app = require('app');
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

require('crash-reporter').start();

var mainWindow = null;

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
    mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
    mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
        mainWindow = null;
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Example</p>

        <script src="models.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**models.js**

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('bdgt', 'username', 'password', {
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: 'example.db',
});

var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: Sequelize.STRING,
    birthday: Sequelize.DATE
});

sequelize.sync().then(function() {
    return User.create({
        username: 'janedoe',
        birthday: new Date(1980, 6, 20)
    });
}).then(function(jane) {
    console.log(jane.get({
        plain: true
    }));
});
```

Install the dependencies using `npm install` and reproduce the problem using `npm start`. Running `node models.js` will show sequelize works one its own.

Comment: @destan has a much better answer than mine or ezrepotein. IMHO you should change accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I found a working solution to this problem, based on article provided by @Josh, and other blog posts and issue discussions. Below I wrote all steps I have taken in order to solve this problem. The **final solution** is posted on the **bottom of this answer**

I followed electron tutorial available in [electron repo](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md).

**The Easy Way**

I've installed `electron-rebuild` node package and run `./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild` which gave me the following error:

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! install error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Unsupported target version: 0.31.2
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "node" "/my/project/dir/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@3.0.10 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the sqlite3 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
```

**The node-gyp Way**

I've installed node-gyp module globally and entered `./node_modules/sqlite3` dir. Then I tried to run the following command:

```
node-gyp rebuild --target=0.31.2 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell
```

and got the following error:

```
gyp: Undefined variable module_name in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
```

**The npm Way**

This resulted in the same results as The Easy Way.

**The sqlite3 forks**

Finally I tried to download few of the [sqlite3 forks](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/network). Unfortunately results were the same.

**Final attempt - The solution**

The blog post provided by @Josh was forbidden for me, but I found [google cached](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:6AMZ-aUXrAYJ:verysimple.com/2015/05/30/using-node_sqlite3-with-electron/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=pl&client=ubuntu) version of it. I also followed the discussion of the [electron issue](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/1182).

Steps presented below should get you a working sqlite3 package.

- Change version of electron-prebuilt in your package.json `"electron-prebuilt": "0.29.1"`
- Reinstall `electron-prebuilt`
- Change directory into `./node_modules/sqlite3`
- Run prepublish scripts `npm run prepublish`
- Configure node-gyp module_name and module_path

  ```
  node-gyp configure --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=../lib/binding/node-v44-linux-x64
  ```
- Rebuild package

  ```
  node-gyp rebuild --target=0.29.1 --arch=x64 --target_platform=linux --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=../lib/binding/node-v44-linux-x64
  ```

I tried to compile using version 0.31.2 of electron-prebuilt package, but it failed for some reason.

**If you are using mac replace `linux` with `darwin`.**

**If your os architecture is 32 bit replace `x64` with `ia32`**

Comment: It works fine when I run `node models.js`. sqlite3 is installed on the system.

Comment: Which version of node.js are you using?

Comment: when I do a `npm install sqlite --save` I get a 404 in NPM. Have you tried `npm install sqlite3 --save`?

Also, have you tried installing SQLite3 globally as the Electron and regular Node environments might be different. `npm install -g sqlite3 --save`

Comment: @ezrepotein I'm using node v0.10.38.

Comment: @warspite sqlite and sqlite3 are both there for me. I tried it with sqlite3 instead of sqlite, but I get the same problem.

Comment: @ezrepotein I've installed node v0.12.7, re-run `npm install` but the problem persists.

Comment: @ezrepotein have you tried my other suggestion, installing sqlite globally?

Comment: @warspite Installing globally gives the same result, sadly.

Comment: @Jon please try my updated answer, this should make sqlite3 work properly in electron

Answer (score 7):

I know you have `sqlite3` installed and working alone but the problem arise when you try to use `sqlite3` with `electron` together. It's because of ABI version mismatch.

When you put a

`console.log(err);` in

`<project>/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/connection-manager.js` line 21,

just before `throw new Error('Please install sqlite3 package manually');` you will see an error like following:

```
{ [Error: Cannot find module '<full_path_to_project>/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v44-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

However when you check `/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/` folder there will be no `node-v44-linux-x64` folder but something like `node-v11-linux-x64` folder. (Simply renaming the folder won't work.)

This mismatch occurs because electron uses `io.js v3.1.0` internally as it states [here](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md) and ABI versions of it and your version of nodejs don't match.

Note that `node-vXX` is decided via your node's ABI version. Check this url for further info: https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues/167

**Solution**

The easy way stated here https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md#the-easy-way doesn't work as-is with `sqlite` but you can follow these steps to make it work:

After installing `electron-rebuild` via following command

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
```

go to `<project path>/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/abi_crosswalk.js` and find your node version, then change `node_abi` value to `44`. Like following:

```
"0.12.7": {
  "node_abi": 44,
  "v8": "3.28"
},
```

then give `./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild` command and wait a bit. Then it works.

Comment: Well, you've written that "Simply renaming the folder won't work." but this was the solution in my case.

Answer (score 3):

If you can run `$npm list sqlite3` and you get a response like...

`MyAppName@0.0.1 /path/to/MyApp
└── sqlite3@3.0.10`

Then the problem is likely that sqlite3 doesn't work in Electron (without some coercing) and Sequelize doesn't know how to express the error.

See [this blog post](http://verysimple.com/2015/05/30/using-node_sqlite3-with-electron/) to get sqlite3 working in Electron. This should fix your issue with Sequelize.

Comment: Spot on. That blog post is perfect.

Comment: Thanks! For future reference, if the post worked for you you should award points to the answerer. You can always upvote other answers that you like.

Comment: The blog is dead, but here's the archive https://web.archive.org/web/20160309223943/http://verysimple.com/2015/05/30/using-node_sqlite3-with-electron/

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this error a number of times, and the solution that works for me is to install `electron-rebuild`, and then run:

```
electron-rebuild -w sqlite3 -p
```

The `-p` flag here is required for this to work, as sqlite3 uses node-pre-gyp.

Comment: `App threw an error when running [Error: Please install sqlite3 package manually]`